# Dict passed as an argument to create an object of a python class changes for every object created

Tags: python, class, dictionary

Basically the title

Here is a sample code

```
class myClass():
    def __init__(self,variable):
        self.variable=variable
    def set(self,variable):
        self.variable=variable
    def get(self):
        print(self.variable)

l=[]

x={'a':1}
for i in range(3):
    t=myClass(x)
    x['a']+=1
    l.append(t)

for t in l:
    t.get()
```

I get the following output

```
{'a': 4}
{'a': 4}
{'a': 4}
```

I want the following output

```
{'a': 1}
{'a': 2}
{'a': 3}
```

Please provide some information regarding this weird behavior. I know that this happens when we use mutable objects inside a class but I don't know enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the dictionaries are mutable, which means their internal values can change. As a result, when you say

```
x = {"a" : 1}
y = x
```

Both of these values `x` and `y` point to the *same* dictionary.

### Solution A: Copying the variable inside the constructor

One solution is

```
class myClass():
    def __init__(self,variable):
        self.variable=variable.copy() # create a copy of the dictionary
    def set(self,variable):
        self.variable=variable
    def get(self):
        print(self.variable)

l=[]

x={'a':1}
for i in range(3):
    t=myClass(x)
    x['a']+=1
    l.append(t)

for t in l:
    t.get()
```

Here we create a **shallow copy** of the dictionary. Now this isn't best practice, because many types do not implement `copy` so you'll encounter errors if you're not using a dictionary as your variable.

#### Solution A with Try-Except

We could also implement the following:

```
class myClass():
    def __init__(self,variable):
        try: 
            self.variable=variable.copy()
        except AttributeError:
            self.variable = variable
    def set(self,variable):
        self.variable=variable
    def get(self):
        print(self.variable)
```

Here, we make shallow copies whenever a variable is mutable and otherwise we just assign the value.

### Solution B

Another solution is to just copy the dictionaries outside of the class entirely

```
l=[]

x={'a':1}
for i in range(3):
    t=myClass(x)
    x = x.copy() # copy the dictionary after passing it 
    x["a"] += 1 
    l.append(t)

for t in l:
    t.get()
```

### Shallow Copies

As an aside, let's try my solution but use `x={'a':{"b" : 1 }}` and increment `x["a"]["b"]`:

```
class myClass():
    def __init__(self,variable):
        self.variable=variable
    def set(self,variable):
        self.variable=variable
    def get(self):
        print(self.variable)

l=[]

x={'a':{"b" : 1 }}
for i in range(3):
    t=myClass(x)
    x = x.copy()
    x["a"]["b"] += 1 
    l.append(t)

for t in l:
    t.get()
```

Here, the output is

```
{'a': {'b': 4}}
{'a': {'b': 4}}
{'a': {'b': 4}}
```

This is because `copy` performs a **shallow copy**, which copies each of the references in `x` into a new dictionary. As a result, the resulting dictionary will contain entries with the exact same references as in the original dictionary. When you have an integer, writing `x["a"] += 1` shadows the previous reference, but of course mutating the `b` dictionary does not involve shadowing, and we get the result above.

Comment: Is there any way to get around the last `b` dictionary?

Comment: I got it! I used deepcopy instead of shallow copy.

Comment: @Zuj3brusu In that case, you'll want to use the `copy` module and call `x = copy.deepcopy(x)`

Comment: `import copy` and then `x=copy.deepcopy(x)` solves the last one. Thanks for your answer. It helped a lot

Comment: @Zuj3brusu Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You are pointing to x from different objects.
x has his own declaration and python understand x like index to your Objects.

```
>>> l = []
>>> 
>>> for i in range(3):
...     t=myClass({'a': 1 + i})
...     l.append(t)
... 
>>> for t in l:
...     t.get()
... 
{'a': 1}
{'a': 2}
{'a': 3}
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that the actual x which I need to pass is a very long dict containing tens of variables.

Comment: So you dont need to create a class. Work into dict. Use update function. If you want I can edit my answer and show you.

Comment: Thanks you very much but I will use deepcopy for now.

Answer (score 1):

Each instance to the class has reference to the same dictionary. Variables in python don't hold objects, they hold a reference (also known as a pointer) to the location of an object.

So each of the instances have a pointer to the same object. Since that object (a dictionary) is mutable, when you change it, it will remain in the same place. Thus all instances will have the same update.

You'll want to make a copy (either shallow or deep) to have the behavior you are expecting.

As a side note, the get and set functions of the class are somewhat pointless. You know you can just access the attribute directly.

Comment: Yeah that get set thing I added without thinking. I just wanted to write the code to demonstrate the thing.